# Firebase functions error: The request was aborted because there was no available instance

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app relies on a Firestore database, and I use Firebase event functions to automate some tasks. One of these tasks involves creating a document in the user/{userDoc}/notifications collection for approximately 100 users at a time.

Following this, another event function is tasked with listening to the user/{userDoc}/notifications collection documents. If a new document appears, it sends its content as a notification to the registered user's device.

Occasionally, I encounter an error stating, 'The request was aborted because there was no available instance,' emanating from the function responsible for sending notifications to the user's device using the Firebase Admin SDK.

I tried setting the default instance limit to 3000, but it did not work. Also, I have limited the maximum number of instances for the functions to 20 but same problem appeared.

what should i do?

Secondly, what happens to triggers that fail? Do they retry?

Comment: Aside from that message, is the document actually being processed? If so, it might just be a transient error message while GCF scales up. If I recall correctly that's what caused this message in the past.